# Java Script running poorly under PHP compared to ColdFusion

Tags: php

I am having to switch my site over from ColdFusion to PHP and I am noticing that some JS, fadeslideshow.js, isn't running to smoothly. First I notice that some images aren't being centered as they should and the code seems to run a little choppy. Any clues for this novice?

Comment: normally javascript executes in your browser, while php and coldfusion execute on the web server. so javascript's "choppiness" shouldn't have much to do with the server-side language.

Comment: Sounds like the Cold Fusion wasn't ported to PHP right. IS it still serving up the right images? Unless the JS is running on the server, it doesn't care about what backend technology you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php and Cold Fusion are both server-side code. JavaScript is client side. So unless your JavaScript is waiting for an ajax request to load, Php/ColdFusion have absolutely no impact on your JavaScript's execution speed. Perhaps you're testing with a different browser than the one you were previously using? That would explain the changes.

You  might want to fix the following

[image]

Comment: I understand PHP and Cold Fusion are the same process, but check out the centering issue for your self. Every bit of code is the same except the PHP and Cold Fusion. And I know enough to check all the top browsers. Novice nonetheless. This is my main site http://www.pauldinwiddie.com/home.cfm and here is where I am testing the new PHP http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/index.php Plus, in IE 8 the testing site is choppy, side by side to the Cold Fusion.

Comment: I don't really know what to tell you without more information. But unless the js is waiting for the server to do something, php or coldfusion can't affect the js. There is something your missing in your analysis. Try some browser plugins like yslow.

Comment: those pages are not the same and unfortunately, I am on linux and don't have access to IE8.

Comment: Wow, I need to fix those errors! What are you using to get them? None of my browsers show these. Some I can see straight away how to fix, others I'm not sure of. Would these errors cause the JS to lose it's centering?

Comment: it could mess things up but it's hard to say. That's the chrome console. Open it using ctrl-j and safari uses it too. Firefox has the firebug plugin.

Comment: I am still getting a couple errors that refer to MIME type text and I don't know what this is. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for all your input; I thought you might like to know I found the problem. The centering issue was caused by some CSS. Apparently Cold Fusion read it differently than PHP. I fixed that. The choppiness was being caused with a JS conflict; one JS was a preloader and the other was a fade-slideshow. I dumped the preloader for now and it works fine.